# Angular v15, no arguments named $title or $input

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular15

I'm doing the following and trying to follow as good as possible the [angular documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) but I'm facing the following error

```
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: No arguments named $title or $input.
    ┌──> src\sass\core.scss
44  │   $typography: mat.define-typography-config(
    │ ┌──────────────^
45  │ │   $font-family: 'Muli, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif',
46  │ │   $title: mat-typography-level(20px, 32px, 600),
47  │ │   $body-2: mat-typography-level(14px, 24px, 600),
48  │ │   $button: mat-typography-level(14px, 14px, 600),
49  │ │   $input: mat-typography-level(16px, 1.125, 400),
50  │ │ );
    │ └─^ invocation
```

This is my css

```scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@import '@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$app-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$light-blue-palette, 700, 200, 400);
$app-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$light-blue-palette, A700, A200, A400);
$app-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$app-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Muli, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif',
);

$app-theme: mat.define-light-theme(
  (
    color: (
      $app-primary,
      $app-accent,
      $app-warn,
    ),
    typography: $app-typography,
  )
);

@include mat.all-component-themes($app-theme);
```

Am I missing something ?

#### Edit

I've changed the `mat-core()` to `mat.core()` *thx to the @O-9 comment*

But that did create further error.

```
./src/sass/main.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: $map: (50: #e1f5fe, 100: #b3e5fc, 200: #81d4fa, 300: #4fc3f7, 
// ...
, "contrast-contrast": null) is not a map.
    ╷
197 │     $primary: map.get($color-settings, primary);
    │               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming\_theming.scss 197:15  define-light-theme()
  src\sass\core.scss 14:13                                          @import
  src\sass\main.scss 10:9                                           root stylesheet
```

I'm still lost here '^^

Comment: should it be `mat.mat-core()`?

Comment: @O-9 could not be. I have the same thing in my project as well and it works fine. In fact, that css file is automatically generated whenever you create a angular app

Comment: @O-9 Indeed, I see that it should be `mat.core()` instead of `mat-core()` good catch. That said, doing so I get a bunch of other errors. debugged it a little bit & posted my further investigation in the question

Comment: Are the contents of the `sass/core.scss` file the same as the contents that you've pasted in your question? The error shows code that doesn't appear to exist in that file.

Comment: @Edric Yes, it have the same content. I also trying to remove the `@import '@angular/material/theming';` but it didn't helped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your legacy typography config contains specifications for "title" and "input" but those 2 are no longer supported by Angular 15. Just take out those 2 entries and it should be fine. The full list of supported entries is:

```
  $font-family
  $headline-1
  $headline-2
  $headline-3
  $headline-4
  $headline-5
  $headline-6
  $subtitle-1
  $subtitle-2
  $body-1,
  $body-2
  $caption
  $button
  $overline
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, could you point me out where I should add this piece of code?

Comment: I have similar error while trying to compile the project, getting: "SassError: No arguments named $display-4, $display-3, $display-2, $display-1, $headline, $title, $subheading-2, $subheading-1 or $input". What do you mean "to take out"? What should I put instead to make it look nice like before? :)

Comment: Have a look at the typography section in Angular Material’s documentation: https://material.angular.io/guide/typography

Comment: In my case, I had `$headline`, changed it to `$headline-1`

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can try the following commands in the order I have listed them before going to the next one. At times you may encounter many variations of node_modules errors whenever you change your angular version

1.npm install --save-dev webpack

2.npm link webpack

3.npm cache clean --force

The screenshot above is an example of the errors that I used to face and I honestly don't know how they just pop out of the blue like that.

Comment: Hi and thx for your help, not sure though how this should help me..

Answer (score 0):

*Temporary workaround*

I could manage to make it work doing the following.

```scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@import '@angular/material/theming';

@include mat.core();

$app-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$blue-palette, 700, 200, 400);
$app-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$blue-palette, A700, A200, A400);
$app-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$app-theme: mat.define-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);
```

*It does looks incorrect to me, so if anybody find a better solution, I'll be glad to remove this answer.*